# How do I prevent from falling out bubble in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have plotted a chart of bubbles using highcharts.
zoomType of That is 'xy'.
When I'm zoom bubbles out of the plot.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug, already reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6296). It appeared in Highcharts 5.0.7 - so you can avoid it by using Highcharts 5.0.6

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8arLy77/1/

As a workaround for 5.0.7 version, you can clip the bubble group

```
chart: {
  type: 'bubble',
  plotBorderWidth: 1,
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;
      chart.clipBubble = chart.renderer.clipRect({
        x: chart.plotLeft,
        y: chart.plotTop,
        width: chart.plotWidth,
        height: chart.plotHeight
      });
      chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.parentGroup.parentGroup.clip(chart.clipBubble);
    },
    redraw: function() {
      var chart = this;
      chart.clipBubble.attr({
        x: chart.plotLeft,
        y: chart.plotTop,
        width: chart.plotWidth,
        height: chart.plotHeight
      });
    },
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8arLy77/